# I am trying to execute the code but I am getting the following error

Tags: testing, junit

https://github.com/PritamKrishna/Testing-.git

Please refer to the link and find the attachments with the error in the text file named Error.txt .

Comment: Please add the needed files in the question itself, try to avoid as much links/redirections as possible.

Comment: Sure will keep that in my mind next time. This is the first time I am using this platform and while uploading the code it said that there were some issues with the code. That's why I left the links for reference. I will try to keep my code more clean the nect time .